# Socket read() and ready() interlock, client disconnect detection

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client, disconnect

Ok my issue is simple. I am trying to make simple chat but i feel that detection of disconnected client from server is mandatory. Chat works fine (without such detection) when i use simple:

```
                if (this.in.ready())  //preinitialized buffered reader
                    this.dataIn=this.in.readLine();
```

I have browsed lots of websites/questions posted here and i read that `ready()` should be ommited since it blocks everything, that may be true since when i delete this `ready()` my chat no longer works, however it enables client disconnected detection.

In order to reach my goal i need to test if `BufferedReader` recieves null through `readLine()` but this does not work as it should either.

```
            if (this.in.readLine()!=null){ //1. check if client disconnected
                if (this.in.ready())       //2/
                    this.dataIn=this.in.readLine(); //3.
            }                    
            else
                this.notice="Client disconnected!";
```

Now what happens when i apply code presented above. Initial if (1) is blocking the inner `ready()` (line 2) which is required to read actual message send over socket (3).

The other "order" does not work:

```
            if (this.in.ready()){
                this.dataIn=this.in.readLine();
            }
            else if (this.in.readLine()!=null)
                this.notice="Client disconnected!";
```

This one also does not allow to send messages through socket.

*Yes, sending/recieving is realized in separate thread

*BufferedReader is initialized only once

Thread source code (if any1 would need it in order to take a look):

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (this.isServer){            
            this.initServer();
            this.initProcessData(sSocket);
        } 
        else if (!this.isServer){
            this.initClient();
            this.initProcessData(clientSocket);
        }            
        this.initDone=true;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NetClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    while(this.initDone){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if ((!this.dataOut.isEmpty())&&(this.dataOut!="")){                
                this.out.println(this.dataOut);
                this.out.flush();
                this.dataOut = "";
            }
            if (this.in.ready())
                this.dataIn=this.in.readLine();                   
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NetClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {  
            this.initDone=false;
                Logger.getLogger(NetClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //System.out.println(this.notice);
    }

}
```

The worst thing is that i have either proper detection of client disconnected or i have working chat.

Can anyone enlight me what should i do in order to combine those two together? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `java.io.ObjectInputStream` and `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`. Use the blocking `read()` method in a separate worker thread, and loop until it returns -1 or throws an exception. Send String objects back and forth. In that way, you can also send messages with line feeds.